# Bind element attribute value to object

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js

I'd like to bind the x and y coordinates of a d3 `SVGTextElement` to an object in Angular 4, without using `onclick` or similar input event.  As the element's coordinates change, I'd like the values on the object to reflect the current values.  By default, d3 binds links to nodes, but I'd like to bind my links to the children of the nodes.

I've investigated how to do this, but I haven't been able to find a solid example.  `ngModel` is for forms, which this isn't.  The "banana" of "banana in a box" (without the box) is for events.  From what I can tell, the events on these objects don't allow for reflection of the current value. I attempted to assign ID's to each of the elements I care about, then I created getter's that would retrieve the element by ID and then grab the x and y values on each tick, but it doesn't appear that's happening.

How can I bind the current x and y coordinates of an `SVGTextElement` to an object?

My current template, the children collection is what I'd like to bind to.  The nodes and links collections are bound with coordinates via d3:

```
<div class="svg">
  <svg id="svg2" #svg width="100%" height="100%">
    <svg:g id="root" [appZoomable]="svg">
      <svg:g id="links" *ngFor="let link of links">
        <svg:line class="link"
                  [attr.x1]="link.source.x + (link.source.width / 2)"
                  [attr.y1]="link.source.y + (link.source.height / 2)"
                  [attr.x2]="link.target.x + (link.target.width / 2)"
                  [attr.y2]="link.target.y + (link.target.height / 2)">
        </svg:line>
        <svg:text class="link-name" [attr.x]="(link.source.x + (link.source.width / 2)) / 2 +
                                              (link.target.x + (link.target.width / 2)) / 2"
                  [attr.y]="(link.source.y + (link.source.height / 2)) / 2 +
                            (link.target.y + (link.target.height / 2)) / 2"
                  text-anchor="middle">{{link.name}} ({{link.type}})</svg:text>
      </svg:g>
      <svg:g [appDraggable]="node" [appDraggableInGraph]="graph" *ngFor="let node of nodes">
        <svg:g [attr.transform]="'translate(' + node.x + ',' + node.y + ')'">
          <svg:rect class="node" [attr.fill]="node.color"
              [attr.rx]="node.rxy"
              [attr.ry]="node.rxy"
              [attr.width]="node.width"
              [attr.height]="node.height">
          </svg:rect>
          <svg:text class="erdTableName" dx="1.5em" dy="1.5em" text-anchor="start">
            {{node.name}} ({{node.x}},{{node.y}})
          </svg:text>
          <svg:text *ngFor="let child of node.children; let i = index;"
                    [attr.id]="childID" [attr.dx]="'1.5em'"
                    [attr.dy]="(1.5 * (i + 2)).toString() + 'em'" text-anchor="start"
                    (DOMSubtreeModified)="domChanged($event)">
            {{child.name}} ({{child.x}},{{child.y}})
          </svg:text>
        </svg:g>
      </svg:g>
    </svg:g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us what the template markup could look like?

Comment: @ConnorsFan Absolutely, I need some time to deidentify it.  Give me a few minutes.

Comment: The `x` and `y` attributes of the SVG `text` element are bound to some `link` object properties. It doesn't work? Or you want to bind to something else?

Comment: @ConnorsFan Right now the links are bound to the node, I'd like to bind them to the children of the node.  Great question, I'll update mine to include these details.